# How to create TikZ file with pixel font size not Pt?

Tags: fonts, tikz-styles

How to create TikZ file with **pixel** font size **not Pt**?

```
\documentclass[border=12]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[font=\fontsize{13.5}{16}\selectfont]

\node (a) {text};

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `13.5` needs to be in pixels not in points; of course with different value.

---

**Edit:**
The purpose of the question might not be very clear.

What is meant is that this part `\begin{scope}[font=\fontsize{13.5}{16}\selectfont]` should be something like `\begin{scope}[font=\fontsize{18`**`px`**`}{21`**`px`**`}\selectfont]` (which does not work BTW).

I do not know if this is even possible, but it would be great if it is.

Comment: Can you provide a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of what you are doing and what instead you want to achive?

Comment: see if http://reeddesign.co.uk/test/points-pixels.html can help you (13.5pt = 18px).

Comment: @Zarko That page is weird.  The conversion of pt to px depends on the resolution you are viewing it at.

Comment: You are confusing with HTML or other graphics which uses px for rendering. Documents don't work that way.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion is easy.  Given a certain resolution in dots per inch (DPI) you can plug in your value for `px` in the formula below.

[image]

From the TeXbook we know that `pt/inch = 72.27`.  For a resolution of 300 DPI and a target font size of 18 px we find

[image]